# SQL to update specified column where datetime column is over a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, updates

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to write a simple database to track jobs, customers, workers, etc.

I am trying to write an update statement to increase the hourly wage (by $2) of all workers who have been employed by the company for over a year.

This is what the `Workers` table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE TWorkers
(
     intWorkerID            INTEGER         NOT NULL
     ,strFirstName          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,strLastName           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
     ,dtmHireDate           DATETIME        NOT NULL
     ,monHourlyRate         MONEY           NOT NULL
     ,CONSTRAINT TWorkers_PK PRIMARY KEY (intWorkerID)
)
```

This is the `Update` statement I have started:

```
SELECT * FROM TWorkers

UPDATE TWorkers
SET monHourlyRate = monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE dtmHireDate = dtmHireDate > 12/1/2014

SELECT * FROM TWorkers
```

I know the `WHERE` clause is incorrect. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE dtmHireDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Your `UPDATE` query will be:

```
UPDATE TWorkers
    SET monHourlyRate = monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dtmHireDate  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: Getting this error when I use that WHERE clause:

Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Can you post the whole query? See my updated answer.

Comment: The whole query is quite long but I can post if necessary. I'm no longer getting an error, however all of the dates have been set to 01/01/1900 and the hourly rate has not increased

Comment: Your update statement is wrong then. The only change you need to make is the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is the update statement I am using from your comment:

`SELECT * FROM TWorkers

UPDATE TWorkers
SET
 monHourlyRate = monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dtmHireDate  > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

SELECT * FROM TWorkers`

Comment: That's correct. However, you mention that dates have been set to `01/01/1900` which the query did not do. I suggest you post the real `UPDATE` query.

Comment: That is the exact Update query, there is no other query

Comment: Then I guess I am out of luck. It changed all dtm fields in all tables.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some searching and experimenting, I fixed it.

The winning query was:

```
UPDATE TWorkers
SET
monHourlyRate = monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
dtmHireDate > '2014-12-01'
```